# Javascript: Override global vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, var

I set the global var "cost_ifCMS = 0" Now i have a function who should add amount of money to this var and after the function can print this.

I only post a few rows of the javascript, because i'm sure there is the mistake and i bet my mistake is for one you nice helpers a easy going question :)

```
        cost_ifCMS = 0;


    $('input[name="ifCMS"]').change(function(){
         var grabVal_ifCMS = $(this).val();
            if(grabVal_ifCMS == "ifCMSyes"){
                $("#ifCMSyes").show();
                $("#ifCMSno").hide();
                cost_ifCMS = + 100;
            }else{
                $("#ifCMSyes").hide();
                $("#ifCMSno").show();
                $("#chooseLAYOUTcontao").hide();
                $("#chooseLAYOUTjoomla").hide();
                $("#chooseLAYOUTwordpress").hide();
                cost_ifCMS = + 0;
            }

    });

var summe = cost_ifCMS 


    $('#summehtml').html(summe)
```

Comment: If you're trying to increment the variable by 100 use `cost_ifCMS += 100`

Comment: `cost_ifCMS = + 100;` mean *"Set cost to +100"*. You probably want `cost_ifCMS += 100;` wich is *"Add 100 to cost"*.

Comment: So, what happens? What is the question?

Comment: On the other hand, `cost_ifCMS += 0;` seems pointless, maybe you do want to set your cost to +100.

Comment: Have to improve my Question: I'm looking so override or set the var. instead of 0 it should be 100. But i will say thank you to learn the operator += :)

But now the problem is, it works, so long i stay in the function. Outside the function, no chance right now. Any idear? When i put console.log(cost_ifCMS) bevore the closing tag of the function it works. But i need it outside, because there are a few functions who will come together at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `cost_ifCMS = cost_ifCMS + 100;` or `cost_ifCMS += 100;`.
The variable will store the new value which is the result of 100 added to itself.
Doing `cost_ifCMS = + 100;` will assign the positive value of 100. This is the opposite of `cost_ifCMS = -100;`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works with your code, but only in the function. But at the end i need the new value outside of the function. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Initialize the variable with `var` before. It should work, it's not inside changes's method scope, so it should change correctly.